# How can I get or extract 18 Wheels of Steel's soundtrack?

Tags: 18-wheels-of-steel

Does anyone have any idea how I can extract the music from the game [18 Wheels of Steel](http://www.scssoft.com/18-wheels-of-steel-convoy.php)? If not, does anyone know where can I download/buy this music?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this response](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070510154252AAiIbTE), there is a music folder which contains the files. [Here's a video that may help](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxXX25YKcec). It may depend on the version of 18 wheels of steel that you are trying to grab the soundtrack for. Would you care to specify so that more detailed instructions can be provided?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way might be to look in the files that came with the game u could then copy the audio files out to another place.
Alternatively you could do a google search to see if someone has posted the files. 
If none of that works for you, you could find the tracks on youtube and use a youtube to mp3 downloader to get the songs that way.

Answer (score 0):

Check the game folder. I think, it had a "Music" subfolder.
I could find soundtracks there for 18WoS:Convoy and 18WoS:Pedal to the metal.
Though they were in OGG format, not MP3.